# List Roman numerals to minimize total distance

Tags: number-sequence, optimization

This is based on a [discussion with @mousetail](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65059055#65059055).

List the numbers from 1-100 in Roman numerals in the order that minimizes the total sum of the [Levenshtein distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 15):

The minimum possible total is:

> 99

This is because

> all pairs of numbers have a distance of at least 1

This minimum is achievable using the following pattern to get from

> I to V: 
>  I, IV, IX, II, III, VIII, VII, VI, V 
>  which can be reversed to allow for a change of tens numerals at the end of the sequence

The full list looks like (reading left to right, top to bottom)

> [image: table]

Comment: Nice. With a slight change you can make it cyclic. Rot13( Zbir P orgjrra KP naq K. Gura erirefr gur vavgvny V gb I fho-frdhrapr gb pybfr gur qvfgnapr sebz gur svany YI gb gur fgneg.)

Comment: An excellent answer

Comment: I wonder if this could be extended to bigger ranges